# column level restriction in SharePoint workaround

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

So, I've been working in SharePoint, and I want to restrict access to a column in a list in SharePoint, but I found that is not supported.

I have a type of incident management, where you create an incident, and it gets prioritized and moved around using workflows, and what I want to do is have an administrator of some sorts approve the incident, before it gets prioritzed and stuff. So my idea was simple, just have a field called 'approved' and a choice of true/false, and restrict the access of the field to an admin.

Are there any known workarounds for this, or do you have an idea I could try to get some what the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an InfoPath form for your list, then have the "Approved" option [only visible](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/73224/20101) to your administrators. You could hard code the administrators into the form, or [configure the form to use a SharePoint permission group](http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group).